# Perché si dice 'in corsivo' e non 'in Italico'?

Tags: etymology

L'espressione inglese *in italics* ossia  *in corsivo* ha origini proprio in Italia. Secondo Etymonline.com il veneziano Aldus Manutius fu il primo ad  usare nella stampa  questa forma di scrittura  nel 16esimo secolo. Altri esempi di scrittura 'in italics' esistevano anche prima (15esimo secolo), come ad esempio alcuni manoscritti di Niccolò de Niccoli.

[Italic](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=Italic&searchmode=none):

> - 1610s (adj.), 1670s (n.) "italic type," from Latin italicus "Italian" (see Italian); **so called because it was introduced in 1501 by Aldus Manutius, printer of Venice (who also gave his name to Aldine), and first used in an edition of Virgil dedicated to Italy**. Earlier (1570s) the word was used for the plain, sloping style of handwriting, as opposed to Gothic.

Come mai questa espressione non ha preso piede anche in Italia e diciamo invece *in corsivo*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I nomi e i cognomi di provenienza si usano in genere dovunque tranne in quel luogo stesso.

L'Italia è piena di persone che si chiamano DiRoma o DaMilano etc.: i loro antenati si sono trasferiti diciamo a Bari e venivano riconosciuti dal loro accento. Ancora oggi chiunque avrà esperienza di gente di cui si conosce meno il nome o cognome e viene indicato come: "chi?, il bolognese?". Da 'il milanese' si passa facilmente all'anagrafe: Da Milano, DiRoma, etc. (questo nel passato). Ovviamente a Milano nessun milanese viene identificato come 'da Milano'

Lo stesso criterio comprensibile vale in genere anche per i nomi: a Bologna la grossa salsiccia si chiama 'mortadella', in America si chiama 'bologna', la zuppa inglese in Inghilterra si chiama 'trifle' e la crema inglese si chiama 'custard' e nessuno sa che sono inglesi.

Questo è l'aspetto socio-psico-linguistico, tornando alla tua domanda, il carattere fu chiamato 'aldino' in onore del suo creatore, come hai detto, e quindi ribattezzato nel Rinascimento 'italicus' e in questa forma si diffuse all'estero.

In Italia si usa prevalentemente 'corsivo', perchè è un termine più ampio, che indica sia la scrittura a stampa che a mano e diversi stili di quest'ultima: l''italico' esiste e viene usato dagli 'addetti ai lavori' ed è una forma particolare del corsivo: 'italico corsivo' usata in calligrafia, anche 'aldino' è ancora usato dai tipografi e indica un particolare tipo di corsivo. I termini antichi originali sono usati come termini specialistici.

D'altro canto in AE si il termine ['cursive'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cursive.svg) si usa per una particolare calligrafia e che in BE si chiama 'joined-up writing', che si ottiene quando la penna non si solleva dalla carta durante la scrittura, adottata dai copisti dell'Umanesimo (e ad un di essi *Poggio Bracciolini*, si ispirò *Aldo Manuzio*); questi termini rientrano tutti nell'ampio termine italiano di 'corsivo'.

In conclusione 'scrivere in italico' si può dire, si dice, ma ha un significato diverso da 'scrivere in corsivo'.